# date() returns wrong week number for first day of year

Tags: php, date

Somehow the return value of the function `date()` makes no sense here. Does anybody know why?

Maybe I am missing something but according to the PHP Manual the following doesn't make sense:

```
echo date('W', strtotime("2021-01-01"));
```

output:

```
53
```

Shouldn't the first day of the year be in week 01? Other dates seem to be broken as well (e.g. `2021-01-05` returning `01` ).
I checked the output of `strtotime()` but the UNIX timestamp seems to be correct. What am I missing here?

Comment: I doubt 05 could be week two if the new year day was on Saturday. However, check you date format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's [DateTime format doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

> W    -    ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday

ISO-8601 definition of first week of the year:

> Weeks start with Monday and end on Sunday. Each week's year is the Gregorian year in which the Thursday falls. The first week of the year, hence, always contains **4 January**.

it return 53 because 01/01/2021 is in week 53 of year 2020.

If you do

```
echo date('W', strtotime("2021-01-04")); // first Monday of year 2021
```

it will return `01`

Comment: This is correct but do you have an example of how to get the correct week number for the calendar year?  In this case `1` for `2021-01-01`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: I don't think there is a built-in function that does that since it's not a standard. If you want one, you have to build it by yourself using math then.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the first day of the year be in week 01?

Like @catcon said, no.

To answer your comment,

> This is correct but do you have an example of how to get the correct week number for the calendar year? In this case 1 for 2021-01-01

```
z = The day of the year (starting from 0)   0 through 365
```

From there, get the day of the year, subtract from 365 or 366, divide by 7, subtract from weeks in a year (365/7).