# DateTime returning the wrong date with Weekday Week and Year

Tags: php, datetime

im very confused right now. Im not sure, if i miss something very important here.

i wrote this
`echo (new DateTime('monday 2023W18'))->format('Y-m-d');`

I was expecting 2023-05-01 here but instead get 2023-05-02 (which is the tuesday right after the correct day)

It seems like the days are always one day of e.g.

`echo (new DateTime('sunday 2023W18'))->format('Y-m-d');`

This returns 2023-05-01 (monday)

My question is: Am i doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Thank you for your input

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568023/date-returns-wrong-week-number-for-first-day-of-year

Comment: i dont get what this issue has to do with my problem

Comment: This might be a bug. `new DateTime('2023W18');` gives `2023-05-01 00:00:00.0`, any day modifier seems to be one day off

Comment: Try specifying TimeZone as the second constructor parameter and check if it changes anything.

Comment: Timezone does not change anything, we do not have time here at all

Comment: It works correctly if you do `2023W18-1` (0 for Sunday), but it doesn't explain the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its always tempting to just write out a long string with what you feel will result in the date you are looking for, but understand that the parser is a rather lax text parser based on sets of rules. So it may not always work out the way you expect.

I've run into a number of anomalies with date parsing over the years. Are they bugs? Maybe. Do the developers care much about it? Not really. It's just semantics of how the interpreter is working in most cases.

What is happening in this specific case? No idea. It could be that it's somehow backtracking to the Monday of last week then modifying to the 18th week of the year... or could be interpreting it in some entirely different way. Since there are no debugging tools to say how it is processing the date, there is no way to know for sure.

What I've learned is that sticking with these 3 rules leads to the most accurate date interpretations:

1. Use ***1*** rule per interpretation ONLY (adding multiple rules often leads to
   confusion of the interpreter), if you need more than one do multiple
   modifications and stick to the other rules:
2. start with the broadest
   of rules then add additional going down to the most specific: use common sense
3. Keep STRICTLY to the formatting rules described in [Supported Date and Time Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

In this case you are looking for the monday of the 18th week of 2023. 18th week of 2023 is the most broad and the monday of that week is the most specific. Following the rules above,

```php
echo (new DateTime('2023W18'))->modify('monday this week')->format('Y-m-d');
// 2023-05-01
```

We start off parsing `2023W18` which is the most broad rule and strictly follows the `ISO Year with ISO Week` format in [Compound Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php). Then we modify it to `monday this week` which is the most specific rule and follows strictly with the `reltext space 'week'` rule in [Relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Why do I use `monday this week` rather than just `monday`? Because `monday` is very generic and it's interpretation is... well, sketchy. According to the `dayname` rule in [Relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php), it is supposed to advance the date until it reaches the next weekday that matches (essentially "next monday"). However, when I added it in this case, it backtracked to the monday of the previous week. Why? Who knows. It's best to be as specific as possible with relative formats. Using `monday this week` tells the interpreter that we want the Monday of the `DateTime` object's current week rather than leaving it up to the interpreter to decide.

***Keep in mind*** that the ISO week of year may lead to some [confusion around the beginning/end of years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Relation_with_the_Gregorian_calendar). Depending on the weekday of the first or last day of the year, the first day could be the last monday of the previous year or the first full week of the next year. So it may not always give you the date you might expect. For instance, the first day of 2020 (which is a Wednesday) will cause the first week of that year to be the 1st, so it will move back to Monday, December 30, 2019 as that week's monday. However, the first day of 2021 (which is a Friday) will move it forward to Monday, January 4, 2021. The link to the Wiki explains this and shows the cutoff points. If you are looking for a different day you may need to add some extra rules to check where the first/last day of the year lands and modify to your needs.