# How to make midnight work in PHP for truncating time?

Tags: php, datetime, format

This doesn't set the time to midnight:

```php
new DateTime('first day of -1 month midnight')
```

It's the same as if `midnight` weren't there.
Tested in PHP 7.3.33 and PHP 8.2.4.

The documentation of time formats isn't very clear. But even if I take an example straight from it, the behaviour differs:

```php
echo (new DateTime('yesterday noon'))->format('Y-m-d h:m');
```

doesn't output noon, the minute field is non-zero.

I've changed the above back to talk about minutes. Which can be accessed with `i`, not `m`. I attempted to correct it, but, as the comments show, I did it incorrectly, leading to confusion. 12 is indeed noon both with `h` and `H`. I meant to refer to the hour being 12 at midnight.

Comment: My answer to a similar question applies here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76165384/1456201

Comment: And you are not telling anyone anything they could not get from the manual, where they of course would go when they notice this happening

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about, here https://3v4l.org/GvpBr the time is clearly set to `00:00:00` with your given code. Within the current time zone of course, so maybe that's where your issue lies? _"This doesn't set the time to midnight"_ - but ...? A different "full hour" value? That would probably be even more of an indication, that you got a time zone issue. Or to something completely arbitrary, or the current time?

Comment: `h` is 12-hour format, `H` is 24 hour format, not the day number, and for noon both would give 12. For midnight, the first would give 12, the second would give 00. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php . `d` and `j` are the day numbers

Comment: `doesn't output noon, the hour field is 12` -- Noon is 12:00. I'm not sure what the issue is, unless you're looking for the word `noon`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`h` gives values from 01 to 12

`H` gives values from 00 to 23 and should be used here